# vba formula why turns out value only

Tags: vba, excel, formula

i throught that my vba is fine but don't know why .formula is not work and those cell only shown value only. how can i force it to formula not value only.

i add more code in here, but the question only about to formula, so you may ignore some code from the top side.
[image: img1]

```
For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
    With Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt)

        For b = 8 To .Cells(8, "D").End(xlDown).Row
            ttl = 0
            ttlerror = ""
            vals = Split(.Cells(b, "D").Value2, Chr(44))
            For a = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
                pc = Application.Match(vals(a), sh.Columns(1), 0)
                If Not IsError(pc) Then
                    ttl = ttl + sh.Cells(pc, "B").Value2
                ElseIf IsError(pc) Then
                    ttlerror = "Need follow-up"
                    ttlerrrorcount = ttlerrrorcount + 1
                End If
            Next a
            .Cells(b, "F") = ttl
            .Cells(b, "G") = ttlerror
        Next b

        'Total count of each sheet
        k = .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Row

        'make sure not at bottom of sheet
        If k < .Rows.Count Then
            With .Range("F8").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
                .Formula = "=SUM(F8:F" & k & ")"
                With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlDouble
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            End With
        Else
            'if at bottom of the sheet do something else...
        End If
        'Total count of each sheet

    End With
```

Comment: What is k supposed to be?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify the speciifc problem. See [mcve] and [ask] for more information.

Comment: the k just find the last row of that table.

Comment: If you want the formula to show and not the resulting value than try this: `.Formula = "'=SUM(F8:F" & k & ")"`. Put a single quote mark right before the equal sign.

Comment: OR, if you want the formula to show and not the resulting value then try: `.Value = "=SUM(F8:F" & k & ")"`.  Also `FORMULATEXT` (or the `Application.WorksheetFunction` equivalent for VBA).

Comment: Make sure the cell is formatted correctly (ie. not as "Text")

Comment: Convert k to string explicitly. I don't know if the implicit conversion will impact on how '.Formula' sees the input (could be one of those strange things like referencing Cells() from the non-active sheet).

Comment: Another thought - check for a circular reference. You sum to the end of the range (last row in the table). Your formula references the same column as your Range.